# WPF - Invalidate a listbox which using as itemssource an ObservableCollection?

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to invalidate a listbox which using as itemssource an ObservableCollection ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate, what do you mean by "invalidate"?

Comment: Can you expand on the question, what do you mean by 'invalidate a listbox'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`ICollectionView.Refresh`](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/).